# Geoserver backup

Tags: geoserver

Y copy the %/data_dir/% folder to another for have  the complete backup of my Geoserver to another, but when I start the Geoserver, not charge the layers, neither the store. Maybe I have to edit some config file or  this have some different ids ?

Comment: If you have the layer data in a database or somewhere in the file system, of course you need to backup and restore these too. Anyways, you should describe in more details what exactly you are doing so that people can help you.

Comment: thanks, my geoserver consume the data from my database in postgis . I make a backup of that and restored without any problem. Later I copy the folder %data_dir% to the other geoserver and when I started not lead the layer or store, I have to make it again one by one.